# Text Input and Button vertically align

Tags: css

I'm having problems getting an input and button to vertically align flush. Both the same height.

I've tried float, inline-block and removed the default browser appearance too.

Cheers

https://jsfiddle.net/qLuo8jd8/

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.editing-form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.editing-input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 500px;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  color: #363636;
}

.editing-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.editing-submit {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}

.editing-submit:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="editing-form">
  <input class="editing-input" type="text" />
  <button type="button" class="editing-submit">Save Title</button>
</form>
```

Comment: They look aligned to me.

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks flush to me

Comment: Worls in ff, chrome, ie11 and edge for me

Comment: @Turnip is right they look aligned.

Answer (score 0):

remove `display: flex;` from `.editing-form`  and check it will work